# binary search a std:map

Tags: c++, search, std

Using c++, if I have `n` integers in a `std::map`, is it possible to efficiently search the largest element that is smaller than `k` in `std::map` ?

For example I have `{1, 3, 5, 6}` and `k` is 4
the returned value should be 3

I know `std::map` can search in `log(n)`, if the it is exact match.

Comment: Maps are key-value pairs. Are you searching for a key or a value?

Comment: I am searching for keys. to make it simple, I shall use std:set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/) and decrement the returned iterator by one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use method `lower_bound`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::map<int, int> m = { { 1, 0 }, { 3, 0 }, { 5, 0 }, { 6, 0 } };

    auto it = m.lower_bound( 4 );

    if ( it != m.begin() )
    {
        std::cout << ( --it )->first << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into [`std::map::lower_bound()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound). Note that it will return an exact match if there is one. `std::set` has this as well.